# Running Multiple Users Simultaneously from one Script in LoadRunner

Tags: loadrunner

**LoadRunner Version: 11.52**

**Build: 4391**

**Protocol: TruClient Ajax**

So I am trying to run a load runner script I have written, with multiple users simultaneously.    The Script works something like this(Over simplification):

1. User logs into system
2. Script/User does something in system
3. Script/User logs out

My issue is with step 1 of this process because I need to run the same test for each user but simultaneously.  Short of writing the same test multiple times with different users for each test hard coded in, is there a way where I could have the LR Controller read in user names from a file (or parameterize it somehow) such that it runs each test with a different user?  Thanks!

Comment: As James mentioned. Please read about unique parameters in the product help. The case you describe is very simple to accomplish and it is on the main flow of many users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way where I could have the LR Controller read in user names from a file

See training material or product documentation.   Parameterization: Unique, Block size.   As you are new to the tool be aware that this is a tool that mandates a large set of foundation skills to be successful, plus a period of training and internship.  It looks like your managers have thrown you to the proverbial wolves.  Expect to lose limbs in gruesome incidents.

Users do not operate to a "clock tick."  Concurrent, operating on different pages and on different schedules within the same window of time?  Yes.  Simultaneous to the point of coordinated clicks on the same pages at the same time?  No. See the book, "Chaos, Making a new science" by James Gleick regarding some interesting insights on user behavior that will forever impact your performance testing efforts  -- I have a dog eared copy from college that I re-read once every five years for new insights based upon my experiences.

Comment: Alright, thanks! This project is turning out to be a bigger pain than I had anticipated...

Answer (score 0):

Not really in any meaningful and effective way, no.

This is primarily for usability reasons (why have something called a 'virtual user' when you can do something like this in the script) but of course that usability aspect has the extra feature of protecting HP's licensing.  HP bills primarily based on number of vusers purchased.  If a perf engineer could simply and easily make their one vuser run as multiple vusers, that would defeat the purpose of darn near everything in their billing structure.

There are a myriad of shortcuts and half-measures you could take but I don't think you'll find too many folks who will instruct you on such methods because it treads pretty near going against the terms of service and a lot of people who have built their careers around HP Loadrunner (like me) won't support such things.  I know this isn't what you're advocating, but just fyi.

With that being said you can use the cheap (now free?) license HP provides for 25 vusers.  If that's not enough you'd probably want to consider going with a jmeter type product where the price is right.

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but this is how I read your question.  Stack Overflow isn't too great around getting clarification on questions, but I'd ask why you need such methods.  If it's truly to simulate more than your allotted number of vusers that's not something HP supports.  If you need to run business processes, but not necessarily simultaneously you can create a longer script.

EDIT: Engrish

Comment: I know this isn't the answer you wanted to hear, but hopefully it was helpful in some way. dc